# Vue.js - access to data from slot's component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a problem with accessing data from the component using slots.

Here's my code:
`codepen.io/anon/pen/BbOEZz`

I want the line:
`<p slot="desc">{{ desc_01 }}</p>`
It started working and at the slot in the template displayed the value with date.

Can anyone help me with this matter?

Comment: Could you indicate what behaviour you are expecting and what you actually get?  It is difficult to help without knowing exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: OK, my post is updated.

Comment: Well, i think there is a small misunderstaing about how slots works. Slots should be placed into components that you want to use them. In your case, slot should placed into layout component to be targeted from parent component. And the data that you defined in layout component, should be prop in child or data in parent component. So basically like below;

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OqoGKm

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of mistakes in your code

1.You don't access data directly from the child. The child communicates with the parent via events, using [emit](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html).

You should

- fire an event from the child
- listen to the event on the parent
- update a variable on the parent.

2.There is no `desc_01` declared on the app. The template is executed in the context of the app and not the child, so you also need to define that property.

```
data () {
 return {
  desc_01: ''
 }
```

}

I've added a code pen for this [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pYOBBV).

Comment: I would not want it to be dependent on the Vue instance. Can we do it differently? Yes, to close everything within one component?

Comment: In your case you don't actually need slots, you can just render the info inside the layout component. If you want the info to come from the parent, define a prop on the child.

Comment: This is a simple example. My proper component has a lot of HTML code. Most of it is always the same, and the part is changing and I wanted to make these modifiable parts as a slot.

Comment: If the content of the slot is coming from the parent, you don't need to access it any more, just let the parent fill it in. It will never end up in the child as a value.

Comment: How to use $refs transferred to the template as a slot in your solution?

Comment: You should try to use Vue.js as it is indented to be used. Communication from parent to child is done via props. Communication from child to parent is done via events. You can also use the bus and Vuex for communication. Passing refs between components is a bad practice.